# Роуты для регистрации. Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Как должны выглядеть маршруты для регистрации:

Для авторизации получились такие:

```
Route::get('auth/login', ['as' => 'login' , 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::get('auth/logout', ['as' => 'logout','uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@logout']);
```

Для регистрации у меня такие, но они не работают:

```
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegisterForm');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Маршруты для регистрации и аутентификации можно зарегистрировать с помощью

```
Auth::routes();
```

Выглядят они слудующим образом:

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login'); 
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout'); 
//Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register'); 
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register')->name('register');
// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Answer (score 0):

Маршруты для авторизации можно создать автоматически с помощью:

```
php artisan make:auth // согласно официальной документации это наиболее правильно
```

Посмотреть список собственных маршрутов можно с помощью:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Такое их использование является лучшей и стабильной практикой.
 Если был полезен ставим лайк!)